# sorting secondary field on text file

Tags: bash, sorting

I have managed to somehow generate myself a bizzare results file which looks like so:

```
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv100_samples_f1.json,0.32955974842767294
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv10_samples_f1.json,0.1822943949711891
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv110_samples_f1.json,0.2645739910313901
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv120_samples_f1.json,0.29959514170040485
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv130_samples_f1.json,0.1982142857142857
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv140_samples_f1.json,0.21814006888633755
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv150_samples_f1.json,0.1887550200803213
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv160_samples_f1.json,0.2225237449118046
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv170_samples_f1.json,0.20413793103448277
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv180_samples_f1.json,0.17142857142857146
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv190_samples_f1.json,0.17335473515248798
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv200_samples_f1.json,0.09504950495049505
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv20_samples_f1.json,0.25921052631578945
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv30_samples_f1.json,0.21734357848518113
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv40_samples_f1.json,0.2786516853932584
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv50_samples_f1.json,0.23666462293071736
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv60_samples_f1.json,0.2426584234930448
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv70_samples_f1.json,0.25702811244979923
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv80_samples_f1.json,0.3188405797101449
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv90_samples_f1.json,0.21703089675960813
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv100_samples_f1.json,0.5630689206762028
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv10_samples_f1.json,0.4421855146124524
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv110_samples_f1.json,0.5385074626865671
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv120_samples_f1.json,0.48465266558966075
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv130_samples_f1.json,0.6061946902654868
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv140_samples_f1.json,0.5345060893098782
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv150_samples_f1.json,0.5061946902654867
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv160_samples_f1.json,0.4723032069970845
...
...
```

The problem is that I have focused to sort on `raw1/100`, `raw1/101` which has worked well but I now realise that I need to sort out this problem:

```
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv100_samples_f1.json,0.32955974842767294
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv10_samples_f1.json,0.1822943949711891
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv110_samples_f1.json,0.2645739910313901
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv120_samples_f1.json,0.29959514170040485
```

as in, I want it ordered as

```
*.csv10_samples_f1.json
*.csv20_samples_f1.json
*.csv30_samples_f1.json
```

currently I am manually doing this and pasting it to google sheets which is disgusting.
Unsure how I can automate this because I also need to preserve `100,101,102` order

any tips would be great

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste to test with you. You currently have about 20 lines of input then another 4 lines of input then 3 lines of output - provide the exact output you expect from the input you provide. You say "I need to sort out this problem" and then show 4 lines of text but you don''t tell us what the problem is with those 4 lines, [edit] your question to state the problem and what `*.csv20_samples_f1.json` has to do with those 4 lines that don't contain that string, etc.

Comment: Also [edit] your question to clarify if raw2 should come before or after raw11, 101_count before or after 20_count, csv20_ before or after csv100_, and include such examples in your sample input/output. That's important so we know if you need numeric or alphabetic sorting of the numeric parts of the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a guess given how much we don't know about your requirements, the lack of relevant test cases in your input, and the lack of expected output in your question, but this might be what you want using GNU awk for `gensub()` with a Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom:

```
$ awk -F'[/.]' -v OFS='\t' '{
    print gensub(/[0-9].*/,"",1,$8),  gensub(/[^0-9]+/,"",1,$8),    \
          gensub(/[^0-9].*/,"",1,$9), gensub(/[0-9]+/,"",1,$9),     \
          gensub(/[0-9].*/,"",1,$10), gensub(/[^0-9]+/,"",1,$10)+0, \
          $0
}' file |
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6n |
cut -f7-
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv10_samples_f1.json,0.1822943949711891
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv20_samples_f1.json,0.25921052631578945
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv30_samples_f1.json,0.21734357848518113
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv40_samples_f1.json,0.2786516853932584
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv50_samples_f1.json,0.23666462293071736
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv60_samples_f1.json,0.2426584234930448
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv70_samples_f1.json,0.25702811244979923
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv80_samples_f1.json,0.3188405797101449
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv90_samples_f1.json,0.21703089675960813
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv100_samples_f1.json,0.32955974842767294
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv110_samples_f1.json,0.2645739910313901
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv120_samples_f1.json,0.29959514170040485
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv130_samples_f1.json,0.1982142857142857
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv140_samples_f1.json,0.21814006888633755
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv150_samples_f1.json,0.1887550200803213
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv160_samples_f1.json,0.2225237449118046
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv170_samples_f1.json,0.20413793103448277
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv180_samples_f1.json,0.17142857142857146
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv190_samples_f1.json,0.17335473515248798
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/100_count0_4751_count1_250.csv200_samples_f1.json,0.09504950495049505
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv10_samples_f1.json,0.4421855146124524
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv100_samples_f1.json,0.5630689206762028
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv110_samples_f1.json,0.5385074626865671
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv120_samples_f1.json,0.48465266558966075
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv130_samples_f1.json,0.6061946902654868
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv140_samples_f1.json,0.5345060893098782
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv150_samples_f1.json,0.5061946902654867
/home/john-rb/ramsve/ab_sft_housing_raw1/data/housing/raw1/101_count0_4408_count1_593.csv160_samples_f1.json,0.4723032069970845
```

The above assumes you want the first non-numeric part of each string you mentioned sorted alphabetically and the first numeric part sorted numerically and don't care about any remaining parts of the strings (you can easily tweak the `gensub()`s, `sort`, and `cut` to add more substrings to sort on if necessary).